Cannot align LiveChart2 Pie Chart Title
I'm struggling to position the LiveChart2 Pie Chart Title.  I've searched the doco and shared my ignorance with my Visual Studio Copilot without success.  I've pasted my code below.
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PieChart.DataContext = new ViewModelPie();

        var pieViewModel = (ViewModelPie)PieChart.DataContext;
        PieChart.VisualElements = new List<ChartElement<SkiaSharpDrawingContext>> { pieViewModel.Title };
    }

    public class ViewModelPie : ObservableObject
    {
        public ISeries[] Series { get; set; } = new ISeries[]
            {
                new PieSeries<double> { Values = new double[] { 2 }, Name = "Slice 1" },
                new PieSeries<double> { Values = new double[] { 4 }, Name = "Slice 2" },
                new PieSeries<double> { Values = new double[] { 1 }, Name = "Slice 3" },
                new PieSeries<double> { Values = new double[] { 4 }, Name = "Slice 4" },
                new PieSeries<double> { Values = new double[] { 3 }, Name = "Slice 5" }
            };

        public LabelVisual Title { get; set; } = new LabelVisual
        {
            Text = "My Pie Chart title",
            TextSize = 25,
            Padding = new LiveChartsCore.Drawing.Padding(15),
            Paint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.DarkSlateGray),
            X = 0.5, // Center horizontally
            Y = 0.05 // Position near the top
        };
    }
}

and the XAML
        <lvc:PieChart
        x:Name="PieChart"
        Grid.Row="0"
        LegendPosition="Right"
        Series="{Binding Series}" />

I've been fiddling around with magic number values for X and Y but am getting no where.  Any assistance most appreciated.
